# Virtual WiFi network

Tags: android, wifi, phonegap

So I'm in a location where I have no possibility of connecting to a WiFi network. I need to somehow connect one Android phone to another to exchange data between them using an app.

My idea was to simulate a WiFi network on one phone and connect to it from the other so I can connect both of them with sockets over the network.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This capability was added in API level 14

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html

You can also create a peer to peer network using blue tooth.

I'm sure this question has been asked before.  You might want to try searching for "android peer to peer network"

Comment: Thank you very much, will be using that!